# Cumulative value in report

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, charts, custom-reports

I want to create report where you comparing opportunity amount each month in 1 year & cumulative amount for each month, for example:

jan vs jan+feb.
feb vs jan+feb+mar.
mar vs jan+feb+mar+apr,
and so on (in 1 report)

is it possible to create this chart on the report?

Answer (score 4):

Accumulation can be done be taking advantage of the functions PARENTGROUPVAL and PREVGROUPVAL. My task was to calculate sums of revenue out of the bills for jan, jan+feb, jan+feb+mar and so on. I created a report which groups the bills by month and entered the following formula:

```
PARENTGROUPVAL(Bill__c.AMOUNT:SUM, Bill__c.Month__c)
+ BLANKVALUE(PREVGROUPVAL(Bill__c.AMOUNT:SUM, Bill__c.Month__c, 1),0)
+ BLANKVALUE(PREVGROUPVAL(Bill__c.AMOUNT:SUM, Bill__c.Month__c, 2),0)
+ BLANKVALUE(PREVGROUPVAL(Bill__c.AMOUNT:SUM, Bill__c.Month__c, 3),0)
+ BLANKVALUE(PREVGROUPVAL(Bill__c.AMOUNT:SUM, Bill__c.Month__c, 4),0)
+ BLANKVALUE(PREVGROUPVAL(Bill__c.AMOUNT:SUM, Bill__c.Month__c, 5),0)
+ BLANKVALUE(PREVGROUPVAL(Bill__c.AMOUNT:SUM, Bill__c.Month__c, 6),0)
+ BLANKVALUE(PREVGROUPVAL(Bill__c.AMOUNT:SUM, Bill__c.Month__c, 7),0)
+ BLANKVALUE(PREVGROUPVAL(Bill__c.AMOUNT:SUM, Bill__c.Month__c, 8),0)
+ BLANKVALUE(PREVGROUPVAL(Bill__c.AMOUNT:SUM, Bill__c.Month__c, 9),0)
+ BLANKVALUE(PREVGROUPVAL(Bill__c.AMOUNT:SUM, Bill__c.Month__c, 10),0)
+ BLANKVALUE(PREVGROUPVAL(Bill__c.AMOUNT:SUM, Bill__c.Month__c, 11),0)
```

The PARENTGROUPVAL delivers the revenue of totaled up for each group. The PREVGROUPVAL adds the revenue form previous months. The BLANKVALUE is neccessary to handle empty responses of PREVGROUPVAL. In case of January all PREVGROUPVAL deliver empty responses.

Please note that the increments of PREVGROUPVAL are limited to 12. So my proposal can deliver 12 accumulations at maximum.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but only in a chart. It is currently not yet possible in a normal report.

You need to use the 'Line Chart' chart type and under 'Chart Data' you can select 'Cumulative'. That will generate a cumulative chart for a 'normal' report that just contains the monthly values.

This is described in detail here: http://galvintech.com/the-most-important-salesforce-report-every-sales-person-must-have/

Vote for this idea to get the cumulative count in reports: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrZV